# ExtJS6 - Grid tpl showing div class as text

Tags: extjs, extjs6-modern, extjs-grid

I am trying an example for `Ext.grid.Grid` from `extJS` docs. I am unable to figure out why the `tpl` is also showing `div` element also as text.

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'employeeStore',
    fields:['firstname', 'lastname', 'seniority', 'department'],
    groupField: 'department',
    data:[
        { firstname: "Michael", lastname: "Scott",   seniority: 7, department: "Management" },
        { firstname: "Dwight",  lastname: "Schrute", seniority: 2, department: "Sales" },
        { firstname: "Jim",     lastname: "Halpert", seniority: 3, department: "Sales" },
        { firstname: "Kevin",   lastname: "Malone",  seniority: 4, department: "Accounting" },
        { firstname: "Angela",  lastname: "Martin",  seniority: 5, department: "Accounting" }
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Grid', {
    title: 'Column Template Demo',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('employeeStore'),
    columns: [{
        text: 'Full Name',
        tpl: '{firstname} {lastname}'
    }, {
        xtype: 'templatecolumn',
        text: 'Department (Yrs)',
        tpl: '<div class="test">{department} {seniority}</div>'
    }],
    height: 200,
    width: 300,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

`Output` I am expecting `<div class="test">` shouldn't show. Am I missing something here?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modern toolkit, cell content is html-encoded by default. For your case, you need to set cell's [encodeHtml](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/modern/Ext.grid.cell.Cell.html#cfg-encodeHtml) config to false:

```js
{
    xtype: 'templatecolumn',
    text: 'Department (Yrs)',
    tpl: '<div class="test">{department} {seniority}</div>',
    cell: {
        encodeHtml: false
    }
}
```